# New tag request: "elinks"

Tags: support, tags

For questions about the [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/index.html) text-mode web browser. There are several elinks-specific questions in existence already.

<s>[edit: ...and I'm about to post another.]</s> I would like to tag [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1299982/266017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the tag and tagged your question.  I also created a barebones wiki entry since I'm not familiar with it.  You might want to propose an edit to it once mine goes through the review process.

Comment: I'll put something on there, certainly. I'm no expert but I'll try not just copy everything from the elinks website.  : )

Comment: @gws please do not simply copy software descriptions from websites into tag wikis. Plagiarism is as unacceptable there as it is in answers and generally advertising copy is not very useful. The tag wiki and excerpt should be used to not only describe the software, but how the tag should be used *in the context of this site*. https://superuser.com/help/tag-excerpts

Comment: @Mokubai What I said was that it's _not_ my intention to use verbatim copies of other sources. I've submitted an edit to the tag, maybe you could review it?

Comment: @gws sorry my mind read it with emphasis on "everything" rather than the "not" which sounded like you were going to copy at least some amount...